# I got error when I tried to get data from server

Tags: php, android, mysql, pdo, android-volley

I faced a problem when I tried to get data from server. I sent arraylist data with volley to php server .

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

list.add("data1");
list.add("data2");
list.add("data3");

String finalRequestedList = new Gson().toJson(list);
```

I sent above json to server correctly and received it on php.but I couldn't run query and get response from server on my android.

below is my php code :

```
$data =$_POST['data'];
$content = json_decode($data,true); 
$in  = str_repeat('?,', count($content) - 1) . '?';
$query = "SELECT * from table where column = '$in'";
$result=$connection->prepare($query);
        $result->execute($content);
        $rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        print json_encode($rows);
```

My goal is to run  these  query and get response from database and back it to android.

```
$query = "SELECT * from table where column = 'data1,data2,data3'";
```

Can someone help me on this case ?Thanks in advance .

Edited :
volley send this json to server :

```
["data1","data2","data3"]
```

I got this error on php (lines are different because I have some other code that are not related to this part) :

```
Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements 
Countable in domain.com/get_data.php on line 76 Warning: str_repeat(): Second 
argument has to be greater than or equal to 0 in domain.com/get_data.php on 
line 76 []
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: why not use 'data1' or 'data2' or 'data3'  and you could use UNION for all 3 slect so you have only one query

Comment: I edited it . I wanted to say I need result of these queries .

Comment: it would help to share the two things: 1) exact contents of the JSON string you are sending from your android / java code and 2) the exact error you are getting on the PHP side.

Comment: I added the json and php error .

Comment: Post your volley request so I can determine if you sent the data using POST or the request body.

Comment: ...and remove any private data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data =$_POST['data'];
$content = json_decode($data,true); 
$in=str_repeat("? or column=",count($content)-1)."?";
$query = "SELECT * from table where (column=$in)";
$result=$connection->prepare($query);
$result->execute($content);
$rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print json_encode($rows);
```